# How does exactly the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method tells me I am right?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Sometimes, tiny little needles hit me under the form of perhaps stupid questions which I need to ask to clear them. This times it's about $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof for limits.
I know the definition, but I need a clarification on this example.

The definition I know is:

> $$\lim_{x\to p} f(x) = L$$ iff $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $0 < |x - p| < \delta$ we have $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

Ok, the definition might be in contrast to my procedure but here is also the "strategy" I understood to run:

I first solve $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ for $x$. Once I know the values for $x$ that will work, I choose $\delta$ such that the interval $(a - \delta, a + \delta$ sits inside the steps of solutions. But to find $\delta$ I must first solve and find the range for $epsilon$ (when I solve for $x$). Here an example:

Be

$$\lim_{x\to 1} x^2+1 = 2$$
which is of course true, but I will verify it through $\epsilon-\delta$: the passages are the following

$\bullet -\epsilon < x^2+1-2 < \epsilon$

$\bullet 1-\epsilon < x^2 < 1 + \epsilon $

$\bullet \sqrt{1-\epsilon} < x < \sqrt{1+\epsilon}$

Now, since $2$ is the limit, those are the other passages for the $\delta$:

$\bullet 2 - \delta > \sqrt{1-\epsilon}$

$\bullet 2 + \delta < \sqrt{1 + \epsilon}$

In the end

$$\delta = \text{min}\left(2 - \sqrt{1 - \epsilon}, \sqrt{1+\epsilon}-2\right)$$

Fine.

The point now is: suppose I say the limit (the same above) makes $5$ and not $2$.

All the "same" passages will lead to

$$\delta = \text{min}\left(6 - \sqrt{5 - \epsilon}, \sqrt{5 + \epsilon} - 6\right)$$

**The question**

How and why the last expression for $\delta$ tells me I am wrong, and the limit is not $5$?

**LET ME SEE IF I PERHAPS UNDERSTOOD**

After a bit of reading and thinking, I think I came to a solution for my problem.

Redoing the whole procedure, I have:

$\bullet -\epsilon < x^2 + 1 - 2 < \epsilon $

$\bullet \sqrt{1-\epsilon} < x < \sqrt{1 + \epsilon}$

At this point I need to find a $\delta$ such that $|x - 1| < \delta$
I then subtract $1$:

$$\sqrt{1 - \epsilon} - 1 < x - 1 < \sqrt{1 + \epsilon} - 1$$

A problem yet persists: how could I treat this? I may find a better estimation, like $\sqrt{1 + \epsilon} < 1 + \epsilon$ hence

$-\epsilon < x-1 < \epsilon$ which makes me to take $\delta = \epsilon$

Is this right?

Comment: Did you notice that if, say, $\varepsilon=1$, then $\sqrt{1+\varepsilon}-2<0$, and that therefore $\delta<0$?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're doing with the inequality $-\epsilon<x^2+1<\epsilon$, but 1) you add and subtract 1 wrong on the next line, and 2) I would expect to see something of the form $-\epsilon<x^2+1-2<\epsilon$ when working with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit.

Comment: What is the definition that you know? You could include that in the question before you attempt to apply it.

Comment: @DavidK Going to edit!

Comment: @ash4fun Going to edit to clarify!

Comment: You're supposed to impose $0<|x-1|<\delta$, but you replaced $1$ with its image under $x^2+1$. If you're interested in the general logic behind reasoning backwards to get the right size for $\delta$, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4292945).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put it correctly in an update to the question:

> At this point I need to find a $\delta$ such that $|x - 1| < \delta$
> I then subtract $1$:
> $$\sqrt{1 - \epsilon} - 1 < x - 1 < \sqrt{1 + \epsilon} - 1.$$

But here's the reason why you wouldn't want to replace $\sqrt{1 + \epsilon}$ by
$1 + \epsilon$ in this inequality: it's precisely **because**
$\sqrt{1 + \epsilon} < 1 + \epsilon,$ which means that by making this replacement you allow a greater upper bound of $x$ and you therefore allow $x$ to take on values that $\sqrt{1 - \epsilon} - 1 < x - 1 < \sqrt{1 + \epsilon} - 1$
would not allow it to take.
But $\sqrt{1 - \epsilon} - 1 < x - 1 < \sqrt{1 + \epsilon} - 1$
was carefully crafted to give you **exactly** the set of $x$ for which
$\lvert f(x) - L\rvert < \epsilon$ in your example;
as soon as you let any other value of $x$ be possible, you are allowing $x$ to take at least one value such that $\lvert f(x) - L\rvert \geq \epsilon$
and you will no longer have a proof.

---

As an aside, I don't particularly like the strategy that says you must deduce the largest possible value of $\delta$ that you can find that will still allow the proof to work (as strategies like the above seem designed to do).
But you very well **can** replace expressions like $\sqrt{1+\epsilon}$
with something simpler if you like;
the thing is just that you can only **lower** the upper bound and only **raise** the lower bound.
To put it another way,
"$\delta$ can never be too small."

So I might work it in this direction instead:
I am going to pick some value of $\delta$ (I haven't decided which, yet),
after which I'm going to prove something implied by
$$ 0 < \lvert x - 1\rvert < \delta. $$
I know that if I ensure $\lvert x - 1\rvert < 1$ (which I can do just by making sure that the value of $\delta$ I choose is not greater than $1$),
then $x$ is in the open interval $(0, 2)$,
$x^2 + 1$ is increasing over the whole interval, and the worst-case scenario for $\lvert f(x) - 2\rvert$ is either at $x = 1 + \delta$ or $x = 1 - \delta.$
Specifically,
$$ \lvert f(1 + \delta) - 2\rvert = (1 + \delta)^2 + 1 - 2 = 2\delta + \delta^2 $$
and
$$ \lvert f(1 - \delta) - 2\rvert = 2 - ((1 - \delta)^2 + 1) = 2\delta - \delta^2. $$
Comparing the two, it's clear the worst case (the greatest $\lvert f(x) - 2\rvert$)
is $2\delta + \delta^2,$
so I just need to ensure that
$$ 2\delta + \delta^2 < \epsilon. $$

Since I already decided I would not choose $\delta > 1,$
I can be sure that $2 + \delta \leq 3$.
So rather than trying to solve the a quadratic equation in $\delta$ I'm just going to try to set it up so that
$$ 2\delta + \delta^2 = (2 + \delta)\delta \leq 3\delta < \epsilon. $$
Let's try $\delta = \min\left(\frac14 \epsilon, 1\right)$;
the $1$ comes from the fact that I already said I will not let $\delta$ be greater than $1,$ and the $\frac14 \epsilon$ is a relatively simple way of ensuring that
$3\delta < \epsilon.$

Now it might seem I made $\delta$ smaller than necessary. 
And I **did** make $\delta$ smaller than necessary; I don't care.
The definition of the limit merely says there has to **exist** a $\delta$ satisfying certain conditions; it makes no requirement for me to tell you what the largest possible $\delta$ value is. 
It only matters that you will be able to prove that if
$1 - \delta < x < 1$ or $1 < x < 1 + \delta$
then $-\epsilon < (x^2 + 1) - 2 < \epsilon.$

Comment: That was really enlightening. Thank you so much! So, to say, nobody would forbid me to choose $\delta/5$ where you chose $\delta/4$? Even if maybe it's not necessary at all.
Another question: since $\epsilon$ is small, could I make use of $\sqrt{1+\epsilon} \approx 1 + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and use it, in order to deduce $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ or is there something I need to pay attention to?

Comment: $\delta=\frac\epsilon2$ "almost" works ... but the approximation is not exact and it allows some "out of bounds" values of $x$ to sneak in. It does, however, give a good hint that something smaller, like $\frac13\epsilon$ or $\frac15\epsilon$ might work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the standard way to do it.

$|(x^2 + 1) - 2 | < \epsilon\\
|x^2 - 1| < \epsilon\\
|(x+1)(x-1)| < \epsilon$

Let's say that $\delta \le 1$

$|x-1| < \delta \implies |x+1| < 3$

$|(x+1)(x-1)| < 3\delta \le \epsilon$

let $\delta = \min (1,\frac \epsilon 3)$

As for your work above.

$\bullet 2 - \delta > \sqrt{1-\epsilon}\\
\bullet 2 + \delta > \sqrt{1+\epsilon}$

Seems to be coming out of nowhere.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! Since I was editing my question, adding a piece right now (before noticing your answer) could you tell me if my reasoning is "good" or bugged? Just to know if there could be another way to go, or if I hit a wall :D

Comment: @DavidK No, I meant to say $|x+1|$ after the implication, I had the implication incorrect.  Fixed now.  Thanks.

Comment: Got it. I'm amazed by how quickly you repaired it!